# C program to reverse a string with new lines

Tags: c, function, reverse

I am having trouble fixing this function to reverse the words from a file, line by line. I cannot figure out how to handle the new lines. This is not an assignment for school, I am just trying to figure this out on my own and I have been at it for a while. I gather that the '\n' character is appended to the end of the word and the algorithm is not accounting for that, and I don't know how. Will you show me how to implement this properly?

```
void reverseWord (char* buffer, int size) 
{ 
    char* start = buffer; 

    // bounds 
    char* temp = buffer; 

    // Reversing the words
    while (*temp) { 
        temp++; 
        if(*temp == '\n'){
            temp++;
        }
        if (*temp == '\0') { 
            reverse(start, temp - 1); 
        } 
        else if (*temp == ' ') { 
            reverse(start, temp - 1); 
            start = temp + 1; 
        } 
    } 

    // Reverse the entire string 
    reverse(buffer, temp - 1); 
} 




void reverse(char* begin, char* end) 
{ 
    char temp; 
    while (begin < end) { 
    temp = *begin; 
    *begin++ = *end; 
    *end-- = temp; 
    } 
}
```

My input file is:

```
    this is line 1
    this is line 2
    this is line 3
    this is line 4
    this is line 5
```

My desired output is:

```
    5 line is this
    4 line is this
    3 line is this
    2 line is this
    1 line is this
```

My actual output is this:

```
    5
     line is this4
     line is this3
     line is this2
     line is this1
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you passing the input to `reverseWord` from the `main()`? The `buffer` contains the complete multi line string?

Comment: stephanie86 Please answer the question in above comment by making a [mcve].

Comment: @stephanie86 Try a more irregular input like `"abc 1\ndefhij klmnopq 2\nrst uvw xyz 3\n"`. With that input you can uncover more of the flaws in the logic. With this input the output reads `"3\n xyz uvw 2\nrst klmnopq 1\ndefhij abc"`.

Comment: Please post a proper [mre] including the includes, input, output code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: if you post a question here in such a "simple" language like C, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like @Yunnosch said. It will get you more people trying your code.

It is sufficient if it is as primitive as

```
int main() {
  char buffer[] =
    "this is line 1\n"
    "this is line 2\n"
    "this is line 3\n"
    "this is line 4\n"
    "this is line 5\n";
  printf("%s", buffer);
  reverseWord(buffer, strlen(buffer));
  printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

BTW, the output I got from your unmodified code is a bit different to what you posted:

```
5
 line is 4
this line is 3
this line is 2
this line is 1
this line is this
```

Well, now to your code.

Your `while`-loop will never evaluate `if (*temp == '\0')` to `true` because its condition will break the loop beforehand. But this is not the cause.

You can look at newlines like any other whitespace character. So I successfully tried this:

```
while (*temp) {
    temp++;
    if (isspace(*temp)) {
        reverse(start, temp - 1);
        start = temp + 1;
    }
}
```

You need to `#include <ctype.h>` for `isspace()`.

It seems to work even for Windows-style newlines like `\r\n`. But you should investigate quite closely that the newlines are correct. You might like to learn to use a debugger for this.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much! Sorry, I have read about the minimally reproducible example and will use this method in the future! Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran your code and I've found some answers that will work for you:

1) If your input for `reverseWord(..)` is a single line, for example "`this is line 1`", then your output will be "`1 line is this`" which is perfect. What you can do now is just call that function for every line in your file.

2) If your input for `reverseWord(..)` is the entire text in a file, then in `reverseWord(..)`, where you've said `if(*temp =='\n')...`
Just write the same thing that you've written for ' '.
This:

```
If (*temp == '\n') {
    reverse(start, temp-1);
    start = temp + 1;
}
```

ALSO!! Make sure that you get the sizes correctly. In your case, every line is 15 chars. (Including the `'\n'` and the `'\0'`)

BTW, consider combining the '\n' with the ' ' and use an ||.

Comment: This worked almost perfect, except for some reason the output was excluding the numbers and read "line is this" instead of "n line is this". I think this might have something to do with it being that it is a file being read and not just a string? I'm not sure....anyway, the example from busy bee worked. Thank you so much for your time.